# HTTPD detecting EC2 instance URL instead of that of ELB

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I have a PHP based application in AWS EC2 instances (Amazon Linux, master-worker/s configuration, with worker/s in auto-scale) and I am attempting to enable HTTPS. The application is accessed via ELB URL, not the instance itself, given below (anonymized):

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = primary.dev.myapp.ourdomain.com
DNS.2 = primary.test.myapp.ourdomain.com
DNS.3 = primary.prod.myapp.ourdomain.com
```

The above is also my setup in my `.conf` file in generating the `.csr` file for certificate signing. (For the meantime I am using self-signed certificate for testing).

I followed the usual steps in installing the certificate:

```
- Install `mod24_ssl`
- Put `.pem` file in `/etc/pki/tls/certs`
- Put `.key`, `.csr` file in `/etc/pki/tls/private`
- Edit SSLCertificate and SSLCertificateKeyFile entries in  `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file
- Restart the httpd
```

The HTTPS still won't work and when I investigated the log file: 
[image: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_error_log]

It refers to the master EC2 instance URL, `ip-10-16-226-221.ourdomain.com` instead of the ELB URL. How do I enable httpd to look for the ELB URL instead?

Comment: Typically, unless you have good reason not to do it, you will terminate SSL on your ELB.

Comment: @DusanBajic My impression is, it should be like this:

User -> HTTPS -> ELB -> HTTP -> Application (in EC2). 

Is this right?

Comment: yes (again, unless for some reason -maybe legal/compliance- you must use https between ELB and EC2). with that setup you don't need certificates in Apache at all.

Comment: @DusanBajic Oh okay, its slowly getting clear to me now. So installing the certificates is in the ELB side, correct? How do I configure that? In the CloudFormation scripts?

Comment: Well, I suggest you first do it manually, than when you have it up and running, you can rewrite in CF if you want. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination/ (the page is from 2010 so the wizard looks different now but it should be easy to follow)